# Bootstrap template header animation

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, umbraco7

I am trying to make the bootstrap header of this umbraco uSkinned template http://synergy-bs.uskinned.net/ behave like the header of this template http://source-v4.uskinned.net/

The first thing is that I will need to do is stop the animation of the header poping down after a certain scroll position has been reached, I cannot find how this is firing and do I modify the css or the javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: You can listen for scroll event, when it reach your declared hight, you can change class of header and make it stick to top of screen, all animation things could be done in css

Answer (score 0):

Edit this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("body").toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 300));
});
```

In the file applications.js to:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("header").toggleClass("up", (fromTop > 100));
});
```

Then add to your css:

```
header.up {
   top: -100px;
}
```